# MacBook connected to ghost network

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, airport

I have a MacBook and it has been giving me a weird issue since today morning. I have a WiFi at home and when I booted up my laptop it showed connected to my Wi-Fi network even when the router was switched off.

I tried rebooting my laptop and turning the AirPort on and off, but I faced the same issue. It still showed connected to the wifi network that had been off for the past couple of hours.

The net did start to work when I switched on the router but I still can't figure out why this was happening.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually connected to the AirPort.  Whether the router is up or down wouldn't matter, as your wifi will show the stats of your connection only to the AirPort device.

Comment: Thanks for replying. :)
When I open he drop down menu, it shows me that it is connected to my wifi connection "WoC" and shows a tick next to it, even when it is off.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @AkshaySawan, from your description, it sounds as if you have two devices.   You have a router, and you have an AirPort device.    The AirPort would be your Wifi connection in this case.   The router is simply providing internet access to the AirPort device.   Because of this, as long as your AirPort is turned on, you will always have a good Wifi connection.    But that doesn't mean the router is on providing internet.

Comment: To put it another way...  your router is not providing your Wifi.    The AirPort provides the Wifi.   If your AirPort is turned on, your Wifi is connected.